# Facebook, allow application to manage only one page

Tags: facebook, api

I have following problem:

I have number of facebook pages, for different websites( some mine, sime belongs to clients, but i manage them)

Now, both my own websites and client's websites should use applications, that will manage apropriate pages.

The only scope for application that I see is manage_pages, but when I grant it application has access to all pages.

**How I can grant application access only to one page, so it won't be able to add/remove posts from other pages?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i do not think you can do that. Everywhere in Facebook docs it talks about "PageS and Applications that the user administrates": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#page_perms