# How can I know if my facebook app has been installed to some page by another admin whom I dont know?

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

I'm letting users install my app on their Fan Pages by using FB.ui (method => 'page_tab').

when they do install it, I call OpenGraph to retrieve the metadata of every page in which the app has been installed (graph.facebook.com/{page_id}). This gives me an attribute "has_added_app" by which I know which pages have had my app installed.

The question is: if another admin (not my user) of the same Page had installed the app in that same page... 
How would I know ? 
would the 'has_added_app' flag be set to true ?

in that case it would be misleading, since my user has not "has_added_app" (it's been another user).

Comment: spying on your users is unethical.

Comment: I'm trying hard not to ask for manage_pages permission (I think its too much permissions ;) ) THAT would be spying on him, if I find a way I prefer not request manage_pages on anyone :)

Comment: Nobody would install it if it has manage pages unless it was specifically a page management application.  Apps with manage pages can arbitrarily administer pages, including posting as the page, changing page info, deleting anyone's posts or comments, and probably modifying page ownership.  You probably know this already, but it's a bit much to ask for for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to check that way?
The `signed_request` sent to your app on each page load of your page tab app  will contain the page ID in the `page` object - unless a page has nobody accessing the tabs you'll quickly be able to build a list of the pages your app is installed on

Comment: yes, but I want to charge the admin who installed my app on his page, so I need to ensure that he's installed my app before charging him, I know he could install my app without me knowing it (by using the url

Comment: I need to charge the admin when I activate my app on his page ID. So I need to know the ID of his page. If I directly asked for that ID, there would be no problem, but users (comunity managers if you like) dont speak in terms of IDs (that would be a usability fail :P ), so I need to offer him an interface by which he choses where he wants the app installed. Asking for "page administration" permission would be the easy way, but I dont like anyone having administration privileges over all of my fan pages, so not following that way.

Comment: Another way would be (as you suggest) asking him to visit the Fan Page where the app needs to be installed, and capturing that ID when he visits it... but that has some problems (how do I ensure that the next page he visits is the one where he intends to install my app?)

Comment: A solution would be: do everything from within the facebook page: he first installs the app on his page, the accesses it, and he's shown an admin interface, so I know the app is installed, and he's an admin, then charge him for every campaign (and if another user accessed the app in page, he would be shown a WIP message). I just dont like very much this solution: I would prefer to only have my app installed on his page when It's active for users, preveiting the WIP message.

Comment: as everyone seems to ask for, the solution would be requestion "manage_page" but for only one page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633524/facebook-allow-application-to-manage-only-one-page

Comment: Why don't you install the tab on the page via the API after they authorise your app, and only display content in the pages which have been paid for? The other option is to detect the payment status via the signed_request, and prompt the admin to pay there (showing other users a blank tab or some holding page)